# Resize TD in a table

Tags: html, css, size, html-table

I am currently re-building a table display page, just wanted to know if it's possible to resize a TD without inline styles, like add a class with width and height?

Example:

```
<td class="Td_class">Blah</td>

.Td_class
{
    height:30px;
    width:80px;
}
```

Probably can, just wanted to make sure for when I make this table.

Comment: Do you want to resize the cell, from the default size, after the page has loaded, or simply specify a size for the cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. I wouldn't call that resizing however. You are effectively setting the width and height of the table cell. Resizing is normally synonymous to manipulating the DOM with JavaScript.

Comment: That's what I meant, I called it resizing because of the way I was looking at it: "It's this size by default, it should be wider.."

Thanks. :)